# How to remove and add class with if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have the classes change depending on what is clicked from the two headings.

If heading one is clicked, I want the font color to change to red and have it underlined with red, which in the class it currently does with a bottom border. If the other heading is clicked then I want that heading to take on the red characteristics. The one that is not clicked will just stay grey according to the no highlight class.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ok991am/1/  I give an example look also of what I am trying to accomplish.

HTML:

```
<div id="page_headings">
    <h2 class="no_highlight">Heading One</h2>
    <h2 class="no_highlight">Heading Two</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#page_headings{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

#page_headings h2{
    float: left;
    margin-right:24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#page_headings h2:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.red_highlight{
    color:red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.no_highlight{
    color:#898989;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#page_headings').on('click', function(){
    if($('#page_headings h2').hasClass('no_highlight')){
        $(this).removeClass('no_highlight').addClass('red_highlight');
    }else{
        $('#page_headings h2').addClass('no_highlight');
    };
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: It is not working exact. Try it in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ok991am/1/

Comment: You should still explain in your question what happens and what you expect to happen. Otherwise other users won't have it easy to find out if they have the same problem as you or not.

Comment: What is it supposed to do differently from what it does?

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/occm1twj/1/) of mine..are you in need of that??

Comment: Alright, I updated my question area. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @RDrazard I think you want them to switch between the two correct?

http://jsfiddle.net/7ok991am/3/

```
$('#page_headings h2').on('click', function(){
if($(this).hasClass('no_highlight')){
    $(this).removeClass('no_highlight').addClass('red_highlight');
}else{
    $(this).addClass('no_highlight');
}
$(this).siblings('h2').addClass('no_highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7ok991am/2/)

First off, add a border-bottom property with none to the no highlight class to ensure that it looks just the same before the click.

Next, you want to the click event associated with the h2 elements, so it should be `$('#page_headings h2')`

Use `this` to impact the h2 we're clicking on.

Comment: I was under the impression that a simple highlight for every heading was the desired effect. In that case, @Leeish's JSFiddle is what you'd want to take a look at.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what exactly he wanted. Really depends on how he's using it. Yours might be just what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('#page_headings h2').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('no_highlight')){
    $(this).removeClass('no_highlight').addClass('red_highlight');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('no_highlight').removeClass('red_highlight');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/7ok991am/4/)

**JS**

```
$('.no_highlight').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.no_highlight').css('border-bottom','none');

    $(this).css('border-bottom','1px solid red');
});
```

The above method changes the border of the currently clicked headinh which i think is what you want.

**AND**

### if you want addClass() and removeClass(), then see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/7ok991am/5/)

**JS**

```
$('.no_highlight').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.no_highlight').removeClass('red_highlight');

    $(this).addClass('red_highlight');
});
```

This method adds a red_highlight class to the active link and removes the red_highlight when not active.

Please try it..